# ASP.NET 4 VS2010 Web Application Deployment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I must be missing something quite basic here...

Trying to release my site to a test server... click on the publish option... and off it goes.
The site is 'successfully' to the webserver... the odd thing is none of the code behind files have been copied.

Should they be there? Why aren't they? What have I done wrong!??

I've looked for some help on the web, can't see it, so any pointers to a URL would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a web site (File->New Web Site) or a web application (File->New Project)?

Comment: @John Saunders: How can I tell... I've inherited this?

Comment: Actually, is it a reasonable assumption to say it's a web application because each of the aspx files has an associated designer page?

Comment: if there's a .csproj file then it's a web app

Comment: @John Saunders: It's a Web App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted (and some kudos to @John Saunders for sending me in the right direction)...

It *was* a web site after all... quick convert to Web Application and it works fine.

Should be noted that there was a csproj file in the solution before the conversion.

Problem solved - thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The code behind files are compiled into your output dll which ends up in the bin folder. As for the site url not working or whatever, it could be a number of issues.. make sure you're publishing to the correct directory first of all. Then if that doesn't work, is probably an IIS issue.

Comment: OK, so if I copy the missing source page into the correct directory it works. But this isn't correct? Why does it require the .cs files.